# Deleting an Entrybox from grid in Tkinter with destroy()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I have a treeview in Tkinter and on double clicking on an item (not a toplevel item) in the id column, I add an `entry widget`. If I double click on another item, I want to delete the original `entry widget`. I am trying to do this with `entry.destroy()` and a `try` statement, that way the first time I double click, I won't get an error. The `destroy()` function seems to do nothing though.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

def OnDoubleClick(event):
    try:
        entry.destroy()

    except:
        entry_text = StringVar()
        entry = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)

        entry.configure(background='#d3d3d3')
        rowid = tree.identify_row(event.y)
        column = tree.identify_column(event.x)
        # clicked row parent id
        parent = tree.parent(rowid)

        # do nothing if item is top-level
        if parent == '':
            return
        #get column position info
        x,y,width,height = tree.bbox(rowid, column)
        print x,y,width,height


        if column == '#0':
            entry.place( x=x, y=y+height // 2, anchor=W, width=width)
            entry_text.set(tree.set(tree.identify_row(event.y)))
        print tree.set(tree.identify_row(event.y))

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

tree["columns"]=("one","two")
tree.heading("one", text="coulmn A")
tree.heading("two", text="column B")

tree.insert("", 3, "dir3", text="Dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.insert("dir3", 3, 'subdir3', text="sub dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.insert("dir3", 3, 'subdir5', text="sub dir 4",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.bind("<Double-1>", OnDoubleClick)


tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the exception you're generating, in order to validate your assumption that it is related to the widget not being available the first time?

Comment: You and Curly Joe were right. It had to do with the variable being local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python thinks that `entry` is a local variable. Because you have a try, you're not seeing the error that it's giving, which is something like `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'entry' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a test to see if entry exists (a common debug test), shows that entry does not exist.  Hint=it has to do with the conditional place statement, which also means that it is local to the function and garbage collected when the function exits (never added to root which does remain).

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

def OnDoubleClick(event):
    try:
        print "entry =", entry
    except:
        print "-----entry does not exist-----"

    try:
        entry.destroy()

    except:

        entry_text = StringVar()
        entry = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)

        entry.configure(background='#d3d3d3')
        rowid = tree.identify_row(event.y)
        column = tree.identify_column(event.x)
        # clicked row parent id
        parent = tree.parent(rowid)

        # do nothing if item is top-level
        if parent == '':
            return
        #get column position info
        x,y,width,height = tree.bbox(rowid, column)
        print x,y,width,height


        if column == '#0':
            entry.place( x=x, y=y+height // 2, anchor=W, width=width)
            entry_text.set(tree.set(tree.identify_row(event.y)))
        print tree.set(tree.identify_row(event.y))

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

tree["columns"]=("one","two")
tree.heading("one", text="coulmn A")
tree.heading("two", text="column B")

tree.insert("", 3, "dir3", text="Dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.insert("dir3", 3, 'subdir3', text="sub dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.insert("dir3", 3, 'subdir5', text="sub dir 4",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.bind("<Double-1>", OnDoubleClick)


tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks your debugging logic really helped me. I forgot it exited the function after each double click so I declared it as a global variable and change from `entry.widtdraw()` to `entry.destroy()`